# Identify similar numbers from several lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, pattern-matching

I have 3 lists:

```
r=[0.611695403733703, 0.833193902333201, 1.09120811998494]
g=[0.300675698437847, 0.612539072191236, 1.18046695352626]
b=[0.00668849762984564, 0.611946522017357, 1.16778502636141]
```

I want to calculate the average of the most similar numbers. In the example above, `r[0]`, `g[1]` and `b[1]` are very similar (approximately `0.61...`). How can I identify this kind of pattern?

Comment: there is no numpy in this questions .. why tag it suchly - or would that by thusly?

Comment: if using numpy allows a cleaner solution, it's just x=np.array(x)

Answer (score 1):

Brute force using list comprehensions:

```
r=[0.611695403733703, 0.833193902333201, 1.09120811998494]
g=[0.300675698437847, 0.612539072191236, 1.18046695352626]
b=[0.00668849762984564, 0.611946522017357, 1.16778502636141]


rg = [ (idx_r, idx_g,r,g) if abs(rr-gg) < 0.001 else None 
      for idx_r,rr in enumerate(r) 
      for idx_g, gg in enumerate(g)]

rb = [ (idx_r, idx_b,r,b) if abs(rr-bb) < 0.001 else None 
      for idx_r,rr in enumerate(r) 
      for idx_b, bb in enumerate(b)]

gb = [ (idx_g, idx_b,g,b) if abs(gg-bb) < 0.001 else None 
      for idx_g,gg in enumerate(g) 
      for idx_b, bb in enumerate(b)]

print(filter(None,rg+rb+gb))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, [0.611695403733703, 0.833193902333201, 1.09120811998494], 
        [0.300675698437847, 0.612539072191236, 1.18046695352626]), 
 (0, 1, [0.611695403733703, 0.833193902333201, 1.09120811998494], 
        [0.00668849762984564, 0.611946522017357, 1.16778502636141]), 
 (1, 1, [0.300675698437847, 0.612539072191236, 1.18046695352626], 
        [0.00668849762984564, 0.611946522017357, 1.16778502636141])]
```

Output are tuples of index in 1. list, index in 2. list and both lists.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to compute the distance between all sets of points. Best way to do this is `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

r=[0.611695403733703, 0.833193902333201, 1.09120811998494]
g=[0.300675698437847, 0.612539072191236, 1.18046695352626]
b=[0.00668849762984564, 0.611946522017357, 1.16778502636141]

arr = np.array([r,g,b])
# need 2d set of points
arr_flat = arr.ravel()[:, np.newaxis]

# computes distance between every point, pairwise
dists = cdist(arr_flat, arr_flat)
# (1,2) is the same as (2,1), so only consider each pair once
# ie. use upper triangle
dists = np.triu(dists)
# set 0 values to inf so we don't consider the,m
dists[dists == 0] = np.inf

# get all pairs that are below this threshold level
ahold = 0.01
coords = np.nonzero(dists<thold)

labels = 'rgb'
print(f'Pairs of points closer than {thold}:')
for i, j in zip(*coords):
    print(labels[i//3] + f'[{i%3}]', labels[j//3] + f'[{j%3}]')

>>> Pairs of points closer than 0.01:
    r[0] g[1]
    r[0] b[1]
    g[1] b[1]

# can easily count the number of points as
np.count_nonzero(dists<thold)
>>> 3
```